# Xcode 6 project folders

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I am having issues since upgrading to xcode 6 with renaming or moving a project.  In older versions I could rename the parent directory of a project safely. 
For example:

from:**mybasefolder**/ios/App/App.xcodeproj

to:
**newname**/ios/App/App.xcodeproj

Now when I do this it seems to mess up the whole build cycle and keeps pushing to the device an older binary and all debugging stops working.  I have been looking through the project settings but I cannot find anything related to paths for this.  Does anyone know why this is happening and where I might be able to fix it?

Comment: I've renamed and moved projects around in Xcode 6 with no problems. You must have a library or search path that isn't a relative path. Did you search your Build Settings for "mybasefolder" and verify that it's a relative and not a static path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be cached data in the "build/" directory. If you have your build location set to "Legacy" in Settings > Locations > Devived Data > Advanced.

Steps to reproduce.

1. Create project
2. Build project, files in build/
3. Move project
4. Build project, files will continue to build to original location, you can verify by looking in Finder, there will be a new folder at the old location with only build/ in it.

Steps to fix:

1. Delete the old build/ dir if xcode mistakenly created it.
2. Delete the build/ directory in your project dir.
3. Clean and rebuild.